# file comparision using python

Tags: python

I have two text files

file1:

```
1234
13454
93837
82739
```

file2:

```
comp i
93837 -4.52
82739 -2.2
1234 -2.36
13454 -2.25
```

I tried a python script to compare files and it should ideally do following search CID
from file1 in file2 and append i value to file1. But unfortunately it is not working.

```
file1=open("f1.txt","r")
file2=open("f2.txt","r")
for line1 in file1.readlines():
  for line2 in file2.readlines():
    if line1 in line2:
      print line2
```

Comment: When you say, "it is not working", can you be more specific? are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? Are you getting output you don't expect? If so, what output do you expect, and what output are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution that modifies your original as little as possible:

```
file1=open("f1.txt","r")
file2=open("f2.txt","r")

list1 = file1.readlines()
list2 = file2.readlines()
for line1 in list1:
  for line2 in list2:
    if line1.strip() in line2.strip().split(' '):
      print line2
```

Comment: Indeed, if file2 doesn't change it's actually senseless to read it again. That answer should be used and accepted ;)

Comment: I'm noticing that This code doesn't do all that the OP wanted, in that no file is changed in the end. In fact, these 9 lines of Python, could be replaced with `$ grep -f f1.txt f2.txt` if printing such lines was all that was wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

The first is that `file1.readlines()` returns each line *including* the carriage return.  This will never be found in the results from `file2.readlines()`, as your tokens appear at the beginning of the line.

The second is that you are iterating `file2` for each line of `file1`.  Needless to say, this isn't the most efficient approach, but even if you want to keep it that way, you need to perform `file2.seek(0)` before you iterate it, otherwise you'll fail to match if the files are out of order, as it will only truly iterate `file2` once.

To summarize, this is the minimum deviation from what you posted that will do the job you want (though, I would caution you that there is certainly a much better approach toward your goal, and it might merit a few minutes thought before just using this):

```
for line1 in file1.readlines():
  file2.seek(0)
  for line2 in file2.readlines():
   if line1.strip() in line2:
      print line2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `readlines`, you can just iterate over the file:

```
with open('f1.txt') as f1:
  ids = set(line.1strip() for line1 in f1)

with open('f2.txt') as f2:
  for line2 in f2:
    comp,i = line2.strip().split(' ')
    if comp in ids:
      print(line2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for count, line in enumerate(itertools.izip(file1, file2), 1):
    if line[0] != line[1]:
        print "Error found on line %s" % count
        print "Line in file1: %s" % line[0]
        print "Line in file2: %s" % line[1]
```

Using some extra magic you don't have to readlines the entire file making it more efficient. You also can use enumerate to get line numbers, and you can even make zip behave like an iterable so you don't generate the entire list in memory while you iterate only each set of lines and the line number.

[itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) For docs.

Answer (score 0):

Other posters have addressed the issue of why your code isn't working, but for a more robust file comparison solution you might consider Python's [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html).

Comment: A valuable library, but I'm not sure I immediately see the application here.  If you can come up with a solid approach using that module, I think it would be a valuable contribution here.